# Interact each row of matrix with same row in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, interaction

In R I have two matrices X and Z and I would like a
matrix W such that the row (i) of W contains row (i) of X interacted with row (i) of Z.

```
W(i) = X(i1)Z(i1) ... X(iJ)Z(i1) ... X(i1)Z(iK) ... X(iJ)Z(iK)
```

Here is an example in small scale doing what I want:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 3
K <- 2
J <- 3
X <- matrix(rnorm(J*n),ncol=J)
Z <- matrix(rnorm(K*n),ncol=K)

W <- matrix(NA,nrow=n,ncol=K*J)

for (i in 1:n)
    {
    for (k in 1:K)
        {
        for (j in 1:J)
            {
                 W[i,j + J*(k-1)] <- X[i,j] * Z[i,k]
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a clever way to do that?

Comment: why the down vote? Is the question unclear or do you just know it has been answered before? If so it would be nice with a vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Not my down vote, but it would be more helpful if you could include a toy example with desired output.

Comment: Sure, but the code already in the post is a toy example. The example achieves what I want and should be replicable due to set.seed(). If you have suggestions how to improve that example im all ears.

Comment: You provide code and sample data with no explanation of what is being done. The term interaction is rather broad. While one can understand what you're trying to do from the above code, it is always good to explain **in words** (too) exactly what you're trying to do or **better, copy and what the data currently looks like and what happens when you do the manipulation.** At least that's my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
X[,sort(rep(1:J,K))] * Z[,rep(1:K,J)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this example, you can do

```
cbind(X * Z[, 1], X * Z[, 2])

#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
#[1,]  0.1913117 -0.4871802 -0.1488552  0.3891785 -0.9910532 -0.3028107
#[2,]  0.2776285  0.4981436  1.1161854 -0.4067148 -0.7297608 -1.6351676
#[3,] -0.3257642 -0.3198541  0.2244645 -0.9400245 -0.9229703  0.6477142
```

Or more generally we can use `apply` for many more columns.

```
W[] <- apply(Z, 2, function(x) X * x)
```

which gives the same output as `W` which we get after running your loop.

```
W
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
#[1,]  0.1913117 -0.4871802 -0.1488552  0.3891785 -0.9910532 -0.3028107
#[2,]  0.2776285  0.4981436  1.1161854 -0.4067148 -0.7297608 -1.6351676
#[3,] -0.3257642 -0.3198541  0.2244645 -0.9400245 -0.9229703  0.6477142
```